# Why My Update Email is not WORKING, Firebase and Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to build a function that update the user email in firebase so this is what I did:
1- checked if there is internet.
2- do user.updateEmail with the email I got from firestore after I uploaded it in the sign Up and It can't be null because I used it down and it also prints the error :

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'updateEmail' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 9769): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 9769): Tried calling: updateEmail("omarkaram1st@gmail.com")
```

see It got the email but somehow it can't send an email;
Code :

```
switchAccount() async {
      try {
        final user = await _auth.currentUser();
        final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
        try {
          if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
            user.updateEmail(email);
            AwesomeDialog(
              btnOkText: 'Ok',
              context: context,
              headerAnimationLoop: false,
              dialogType: DialogType.INFO,
              animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
              title: 'Info',
              desc: 'A Reset Email Has Been Sent To $email',
              btnOkOnPress: () {},
            )..show();
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      } on SocketException catch (_) {
        AwesomeDialog(
          btnOkText: 'Retry',
          context: context,
          headerAnimationLoop: false,
          dialogType: DialogType.ERROR,
          animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
          title: 'Error',
          desc:
              'Make Sure That You Have an Internet Connection Before Pressing Retry',
          btnOkOnPress: () =>
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/HomePage'),
        )..show();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a code snippet to better understand your scenario?

Comment: sorry forgot to do it XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `user` is null in your call to `user.updateEmail(email)`. We can't say why that is from the code you shared, but the quick way to prevent the error is to check for `null` after calling `await _auth.currentUser()`.

```dart
final user = await _auth.currentUser();
if (user != null) {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  try {
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      user.updateEmail(email);
      …
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
} else {
  // Do something relevant when no user is signed in
}
```

Comment: I did like what you said but it didn't detect if the user is null.

Comment: In that case the error message is coming from somewhere else. You might want to run the code in a debugger, and step over the `user.updateEmail(email)` call to see if that is the one failing.